# Cannot resolve symbol 'createDefault' in JDABuilder using SDK 15, IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, discord-jda

I am trying to make a discord bot using IntelliJ and I followed [these instructions](https://medium.com/discord-bots/making-a-basic-discord-bot-with-java-834949008c2b) for the basics.

Now if I try to run the program it stop at "`Connected to Websocket`", even though I am sure that it also needs to show "`Loading finished`" or something. Here are some [screenshots](https://imgur.com/gallery/B2TzvEs).
After that I tried using `JDA bot = JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build;`, but I keep getting
" `Cannot resolve method 'createDefault' in 'JDABuilder'` ".

Does Anione know why and how I can fix this?

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType; // Enum waaronder BOT als een van de constanten.
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder; //Library voor de Discord REST api en de Websocket-event voor java.
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        // builder is nu de bot constante dat ik ga gebruiken
        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);

        String token = "NzgwNzA1MjA0OTM2Mzc2MzYw.X7y-YQ.-p51yl7GnUH_Cx1eRNbDKTxhvtU";

       JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build();
        builder.setToken(token);
        builder.addEventListener(new Main()); //Een nieuwe instance van main in JDABuilder registreren.
        builder.buildAsync(); //Moet asynchroon zijn omdat het een internet pull ding is.

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
        //methode van listeneradapter
        System.out.println("we received a message from" +
                event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
                event.getMessage().getContentDisplay()
        );

        //contentRaw zodat we de content krijgen net wanner de user het stuurt.
        if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!ping")) {
            //queue niet vergeten callen, anders wordt het bericht nooit verstuurd
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong!").queue();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Update to the latest version of JDA https://bintray.com/dv8fromtheworld/maven/JDA/4.2.0_222

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to use latest JDA. Currently, it's 4.2.0_222.
and build your bot like this

```java
public class Main extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
            .addEventListeners(new Main())
            .build()
            .awaitReady();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
        //methode van listeneradapter
        System.out.println("we received a message from" +
                event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
                event.getMessage().getContentDisplay()
        );

        //contentRaw zodat we de content krijgen net wanner de user het stuurt.
        if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!ping")) {
            //queue niet vergeten callen, anders wordt het bericht nooit verstuurd
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong!").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

See more in github wiki.
https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki

P.S. using constructor of JDABuilder is deprecated on 4.2.0.